# TYPO3: delete pages records with no pid

Tags: mysql, typo3

I am working with a TYPO3 4.5 with many old records. I have cleared tt_conten and so on. Now I got the problem, that I must delete some pages records, that do not have an corresponding parent page record.

With `DELETE from pages where pid not in (SELECT uid FROM pages)` I get an error

```
You can't specify target table 'pages' for update in FROM clause
```

Is there any workaround for deleting the records in only one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you create a **backup of your TYPO3 database** before running one of the following statements.

In order to delete all pages, which do not have a uid in the `pages` table, you can use the following statement.

```
DELETE FROM pages WHERE pid NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT uid FROM pages) AS X) ;
```

This enhances your original statement, but there is something you have missed, so **don't use it!**

The statement above removes **all pages**, which do not have a have any **correspondig uid** in the table `pages` - this includes **all pages on the top level of you pagetree** (which have pid = 0), so your pagetree will be **empty and unuseable**.

To exclude top level pages, use the following statement.

```
DELETE FROM pages WHERE pid NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT uid FROM pages) AS X) AND pid > 0;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This query is exactly what I am looking for and works very fine. I worked with a database dump, because the original one has a size of 1.6 GB, which will be a big problem, if crashed ;)
Now my pages table is clear from nominal members.